# Is it ok to memoise a nested function?

Tags: r, memoise

I have a function of the below form. I vectorized it using `purrr::map` rather than using `vectorize` following [this advise](https://www.jimhester.com/post/2018-04-12-vectorize/).

```
load_data <- function(key){
  load_data_one <- function(key){
    ...
    # somehow retrieve data based on key
    ...
    data
  }
  # create result allowing key to be a vector
  result <- map_dfr(key, load_data_one) 
}
```

The routine to retrieve data is quite expensive. Having discovered the [memoise package](https://memoise.r-lib.org/), I want to figure out the best way to use it in this situation. Ideally, I want to put it around the nested function `load_data_one`, so I imagine that when I call `load_data` for a vector, than only the unknown results would be calculated. If I memoise `load_data` instead, and I pass one vector only slightly different to another one that I passed earlier, would the memoise function be smart enough to only calculate the new elements? Also, are there any other issues related to applying memoise to the nested function `load_data_one`, that would require me to maybe put it outside rather than within `load_data`?

Comment: I suggest you define `load_data_one <- memoise(function(..) ..)` _outside_ of `load_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you define and memoise the `load_data_one` function externally:

```r
load_data_one <- memoise(function(key){
  ...
  # somehow retrieve data based on key
  ...
  data
})

load_data <- function(key){
  # create result allowing key to be a vector
  result <- map_dfr(key, load_data_one) 
}
```

This way, the memoization is done per individual `key`, so if you start with `load_data(c(1,3))` and then call `load_data(c(1,2,3))`, the second call will only calculate for `2`, recalling the memoized results for `1` and `3`.